# How to access the local files located within the plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin project, which copies some resource files from its own to another project.
How can I refer the local files?  Currently, I try like this, but it does not work.

`FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("image.jpg");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270197/java-in-eclipse-where-do-i-put-the-images-on-the-filesystem-that-i-want-to-lo).

Basically you should put your files inside your project folder structure and reference it with relatives path. To get the files you should use

```
MyJavaClass.getClass().getResources("relative_path");
```

Comment: No.  I dont need any Java class' resources.  I need to read any text file, or copy images, audio files etc.......  Could you please help.