# Loading an ImageIcon from a source

Tags: image, imageicon

i am making a game and i put some images on my ide/images folder but program gives null pointer exception error.my code for loading imageicon is like this

```
 ImageIcon ac=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/actor.jpg"));
 ImageIcon ac1=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/actor_shoot.jpg"));
    //some codes

Image n=ac.getImage();
 //some codes
```

i tried but couldn't find,whats your suggestions?thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java in Eclipse: Where do I put files on the filesystem that I want to load using getResource? (e.g. images for an ImageIcon)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270197/java-in-eclipse-where-do-i-put-files-on-the-filesystem-that-i-want-to-load-usin)

Answer (score 0):

Try with an absolute path ? ("/images/actor.jpg") ?

Comment: its my netbeans/images folder.cant i do that.?

Comment: Well I believe the only rule is that your resources should be in your classpath. You probably want to include said resources in your generated jar file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Is your folder **/images** resides in same diretory in which your class is?

i.e., is your class is also in **/ide** folder?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the path. Are the files really in the images folder?
- Are they called what you say there are called?
- Are they the right case, if you're on a case-sensitive file system (in other words that actor.jpg and ACTOR.JPG are two different files)?
- Are the images a [resource](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html#package)? (Also look [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic13061.html).)
- Try doing step-by-step what is described [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html) (NetBeans documentation).

Comment: I added another link. Try the NetBeans documentation.