# Image is not being displayed with setIcon()

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I have the following code in my program:

```
JLabel status = new JLabel();  
status.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));  
status.setBounds(400, 30, 380, 200);
status.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:........./logo2.png")); 
status.setLocation(50, 750);
add(status);
```

But now I want to remove the path from `setIcon(new ImageIcon("path"))` to an image that I have inside a folder in my project.

I tried to do this:

```
status.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/folder/logo2.png"));
```

But it didn't display anything.

I find [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912041/java-swing-imageicon-where-to-put-images-solved) and tried this too:

```
ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("src/files/logo2.png"));
```

But it gives me a NullPointer.

This is the structure of my project:

[image]

How can I display this image correctly?

Comment: Please, show folders structure of your project.

Comment: ok, I just edited my question

Comment: Did you try `ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/files/logo2.png"));`?

Comment: First, don't include the reference to "src", ever, in your code, "src" will not exist once the app is built. Second, AFAIK, resources can't be stored within the "src" directory and should be stored within some kind of resources directory at the same level as the "src" directory and included within the class/build path of eclipse for the given project.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, [Second statement not true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435) :-)

Comment: @peeskillet Really, then why does it never work for people?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't know. Everything in the src is included, just like a regular package. That's the default behavior

Comment: @peeskillet Does it work from within the IDE as well?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yea, everything in the src gets copied to the `bin`, and that's where all the classes are compiled to when you run. Just like netbeans temporarily copies everything and compiles to the `build`

Comment: @Rikkin: Hopefully this thread, related to, how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), might be of some help on the topic :-)

Comment: BTW - Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look you have to create a new Folder under the Project folder, call it resources or any thing you want. After that you can refer to your resources as `getClass().getResource("resources/thefile.png").toFile()`
Hope that helps