# NullPointerException when reading from BufferedReader, only when ran as a jar

Tags: java

I am trying to read the names of some xml files from a folder located at `src > Truss > xml`. The main class is in the `Truss` directory. It reads the files fine when the program is run from eclipse however throws this error when exported to a jar and run: (this error is copied from cmd, not eclipse console)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at Truss.main.initiate(main.java:167)
        at Truss.main.<init>(main.java:729)
        at Truss.main.main(main.java:110)
```

Here is the code:

```
try {
    InputStream in = main.class.getResourceAsStream("xml");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String profileName;

    while((profileName = input.readLine()) != null) {
        loadProfile(profileName.substring(0, profileName.length() - 4));
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The constructor for the while loop is line 167.

Comment: Probably the resources aren't included in the JAR or are in a different folder inside it. Open the JAR and check.

Comment: Also, just out of double checking, can you put something like a print statement inside the while loop to see if it happens on the first iteration or after a few cycles?

Comment: I have been trying to open the jar but cannot get the archive tool to work. I tried adding it to my path variable but it doesnt work.

Comment: execute the jar `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Comment: It happens on the first iteration @DiegoMartinoia

Comment: `jar tvf jarfile.jar` will show you what in there... "It doesn't work" doesn't really explain what you're seeing.

Comment: @JonSkeet when i try the `jar` command it says it is not a recognised internal or external command

Comment: @AlexA So how did you build the JAR file that you're running?

Comment: @EJP Right click on the project in the package explorer in eclipse > export > runnable jar file > extract required libraries into generated jar > finish

Comment: @AlexA So put this resource into the source tree in the appropriate place and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `getResourceAsStream()` returned null, and you didn't check it.

The resource requested was not in the JAR file under that name.

Comment: How would I go about adding it to the jar file under that name?

Comment: He's getting error on the while line. If "in" was null, he'd get NPE on the construction of the BufferedReader, not on the while line. Or did I get it wrong, @AlexA ?

Comment: @AlexA With the JAR tool or your IDE. As you're looking for it as a file called `"xml"` in the same package as `main.class`, that's where it should be.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia The `BufferedReader` itself can't be null, or the `InputStreamReader`, so the input stream is the only other choice.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood OP's "The constructor for the while loop is line 167." I thought he meant he was throwing NPE on the while line.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia The OP's statement about the 'constructor for the while loop' is meaningless, but it *is* throwing on the `while` line. See the stack trace. It starts at the `readLine()` call. It's your assumption about the NPE when constructing that's at fault. Also there is no way that `while` loop can fail after a few iterations.

Comment: I tried scratching that same example in a Java main: If I pass a null to either the BufferedReader or the InputStreamReader constructor as argument, I get thrown NPE immediately at the construction, not after I try to read from it. Maybe it's my IDE doing some magic.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia it is throwing an NPE on the while line from the readLine() method.

Comment: @EJP I have the xml folder in the same directory as main.class however it still does not work. The 'xml' folder contains 2 xml files and I just need to retrieve their name, if that helps.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoa Neither the `BufferedReader` nor the `InputStreamReader` can be null. They are both constructed with the `new` operator without any exception being thrown. In any case the code couldn't possibly get so far into their `readLine()` and `read()` methods respectively if either was null. The input stream is the only thing left.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've shown, I can only guess you didn't package the resource files properly in the jar. Please have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270197/java-in-eclipse-where-do-i-put-files-on-the-filesystem-that-i-want-to-load-usin%23). Note that the resource folder should be under the src folder (where the .java files in), not the build folder (.class files).

**Update**

Just noticed that your "xml" is actually a folder, you can't use getResourceAsStream(). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20073154/2189796) shows a way of enumerating jar entry that may be your solution.

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question is incorrect. Resources are not files or directories, and cannot be listed with the `File` class. The poster's protestations notwithstanding.

Comment: @EJP Yes, you're right...Seems like listing jar entry is the only solution?